# Show that the rectangular box of maximum volume inscribed in a sphere of radius $r$ is a cube

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Reading an old calculus book I have found this interesting exercise:

"Show that the rectangular box of maximum volume inscribed in a sphere of radius $r$ is a cube"

I solved this using Lagrange. But I think this can be solved using partial derivatives. However, I'm not entirely sure about this. So I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Take $z$ for example and write in terms of $r, x, y$ in your volume equation ($V$). Now set partial derivatives of $V$ wrt $x, y$ to zero to find critical points.

Comment: @MathLover  So I can take z for example and write in terms of r, x, y in my volume equation (V). Now I set the partial derivatives of V with respect to x, and y to zero to find the critical points. After this, I can know the behavior of x and y. The idea is to show that x = y = z at its maximum. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I just added some details. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphere is given by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$.

For the rectangular box with center at the origin,

$V = 8 xyz = 8xy \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}$

$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = 8y \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}  - \frac{8x^2y}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2}}$

To find critical points, we equate it to zero.

As $\sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - y^2} \ne 0$ in a sphere, we get $8y (r^2 - x^2 - y^2)  - 8x^2y = 0$

Again as $y \ne 0$, $2x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.

Similarly from the other partial derivative (wrt $y$), we get $2y^2 + x^2 = r^2$

Solving them for $x, y$ and then plugging into equation of sphere to find $z$, we will notice they are all equal and of length $\frac{2r}{\sqrt3}$.

Comment: Quick question on this: how do you show that the maximum volume is achieved when the box is "centered" around $(0, 0, 0)$? It feels pretty obvious to me, but curious if you have a proof of that.

Comment: @roundsquare if I translate this problem to $2D$ and say I am asked to prove the max area of a rectangle is square. The only way I can have a rectangle in a circle with all vertices at the circumference of the circle is when it is centered at the center of the circle - due to symmetry. Diagonal has to be the diameter as the angle is $90^0$. The same is true in sphere due to symmetry. Now if the question is for a quadrilateral, the proof would be different and definitely more difficult.

Comment: @MathLover  why $V = 8xyz$? I understand everything very well, but the number 8 that appears in the volume equation (V) is not very clear to me. I thought that $V = xyz$, which is perhaps part of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @JhoseElijah As the center of the rectangle and sphere is at the origin, if one end of an edge of the rectangular box is is on the sphere at $(x, y, z)$, the other is at $(-x, y, z)$. So the length is $2x$. Please note all the vertices are on the surface of the sphere so $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$.

Comment: @MathLover Now I understand very well. Thank you so much.