# Maximize volume of square inside unit sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, partial-derivative, volume, lagrange-multiplier

I have a problem
"What is the maximum possible volume of a rectangular box that can be inscribed in the unit sphere?"

The thing to maximize is $8xyz$ (volume of a sphere with coords $(x,y,z)$) and the restraints are $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

The equations I got are

$8yz = \lambda * 2x$

$8xz = \lambda * 2y$

$8xy = \lambda * 2z$

Which can be solved for their respective variables and plugged into the restraint to get

$(4yz)^2 + (4xz)^2 + (4xy)^2 = \lambda ^2$

Which (as far as I can tell) isn't easily solvable.

Did I miss a step or confuse the process? It would be super helpful if someone could walk through the problem

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3913209

Comment: @Jitendra Singh what does that mean?

Comment: @JoeJameson The formula of the volume is not correct. I think you mean $8xy\color{red}{z}$

Comment: ah yes whoops I will change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let me give you a general case.

Let $(x,y,z)$ be the corner of the box in the positive octant, with sides parallel to the axes. Then the volume of the box is $8xyz$. The sphere of radius $a$ is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$.

So to answer the question we want to maximise the function:

$\displaystyle f(x,y,z)=8xyz$

with the constraint:

$\displaystyle g(x,y,z)=0$ where $\displaystyle$
$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2.$

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers we know:

$\displaystyle\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y,z)$ at the maximum.

Calculating the gradients:

$\displaystyle\nabla f(x,y,z)=(8yz,8xz,8xy)$, and

$\displaystyle\nabla g(x,y,z)=(2x,2y,2z)$

So we have:

$\displaystyle 8yz=2\lambda x,$
$\displaystyle 8xz=2\lambda y,$
$\displaystyle 8xy=2\lambda z$
Dividing 1. by 2. we obtain:

$\displaystyle\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x}{y} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x^2=y^2$

Similarly dividing 2. by 3. we get $y^2=z^2$, so that means $x^2=y^2=z^2$

Returning to our constraint equation, $g(x,y,z)=0$, we obtain:

$\displaystyle 3x^2=a^2 \Longrightarrow x=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}} $

Which means $x=y=z=\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}$

So returning to the volume, the maximal volume is:

$\displaystyle f\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\frac{8a^3}{3\sqrt{3}}$

where $a$ is the radius of the sphere.

Now find the volume in a unit sphere.

Comment: Silly me, I was thinking that I couldn't divide the equations and manipulate them. Thank you